# CMIS Query Path Contain Number not working

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

**I am trying to fetch all documents from alfresco using path**

```
SELECT cmis:path,cmis:objectId,cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds
FROM cmis:folder
WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_tite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:PIM_x0020_Data//*\"')
```

is working fine but when add one more column in query it is not working

```
SELECT cmis:path,cmis:objectId,cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds
FROM cmis:folder
WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_site/cm:documentLibrary/cm:3600009//*\"')
```

and this is throwing Exception

> ERROR [hsRndDatasheetJob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob] (hsRndDatasheetJob) [HSLoggingAspect] Cause : {}
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: 05090122 Request failed 400 /solr4/alfresco/cmis?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=100&df=TEXT&start=0&loca
>   le=en_IN&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&cmisVersion=CMIS_1_1&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487)
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:145)
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$3.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:600)
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132)
>           at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionIterator.hasNext(CollectionIterator.java:48)
>           at com.hs.alfresco.services.impl.HSBaseAlfrescoService.getDocumentsByPath(HSBaseAlfrescoService.java:302)
>           at com.hs.alfresco.services.impl.HSBaseAlfrescoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ee750fc3.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

Comment: But they're not the same query, one does:
`PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_tite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:PIM_x0020_Data//*\"'`
And the other does: `'PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_site/cm:documentLibrary/cm:3600009//*\"'`

Please check again using the same String and make sure the issue isn't due to the different `Contains` seciton

Comment: PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_tite/cm:documentLibrary/cm:PIM_x0020_Da‌​ta/cm:3600009//*\"'

is also not working

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the fact that your folder starts with number. Look into ISO9075, encoding your string should do the trick.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-iso9075Encode.html